# X11 Style Copy on Select in Windows?

Tags: windows, mouse

Is there a way to configure MS Windows to copy text to the clipboard immediately when it is selected? Or is there an add-on utility that does this? I am thinking of the X11 style where merely selecting puts the text in the clipboard and a single mouse-click pastes it.

Comment: X11 has two clipboards; select/middle-click and control-c/control-v are different clipboards (well, or at least are supposed to be, some apps are broken)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've never tried it, but the [True X-Mouse Gizmo](http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/nt/TXMouse/) looks like it will do exactly what you want.

Comment: I tried it for a few days. It does exactly what I want but it also does a few things I don't want, and it's not configurable. Nevertheless, it's the best answer and it might work for some people.

Comment: It hijack the middle mouse button on win 10. Can't close browser tabs for example. Otherwise cool.

Answer (score 6):

I tried the True X-Mouse Gizmo and it was cool but the lack of configuration options didn't work for me either.  AutoClipX is another solution:

http://12bytes.org/software/autoclipx

It's not free, but he's only asking for $5.

Comment: It seems it's free now, and it works really better than True X-Mouse.

Comment: As a Linux user who uses True X-Mouse Gizmo when on Windows, I find AutoClipX to be far superior. Thank you!

Comment: Just my 2c: AutoClipX "paste at cursor" mode (which is how X11 paste works) didn't work for me + the program seems to be loaded with other features like clipboard manager, clipboard save etc. and sligthly weird 'fancy' UI

Comment: Amazing find, thanks @AntoniusBloch. Much better than my old AutoHotKey hacks. I'll test a few more days, but if it continues working properly, I'll certainly donate the $5 he/she was originally asking for.

Answer (score -1):

I just tried DragKing and it seems to work fine:

http://www.dcmembers.com/skrommel/download/dragking/

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.